# Using API to convert bundled orders to shipments - Not Working

Tags: magento-1, ce-1.4.0.1

I'm trying to convert bundled product orders to shipments, but the API keeps returning NULL.  I've dug into the code a little bit and it looks like:

```
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment($itemsQty);
```

is return NULL

The orders can convert to shipments fine in the Admin, any idea why the API would be failing?

My API call is very simple and works for all other product types:

```
$newShipmentId = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order_shipment.create', array($orderincrmentid, array()));
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You did not fill in the `itemsQty` array and left it empty: `array();`

A proper call should look like this:

```
$orderIncrementId = '200000006';
$itemsQty = array('3' => '3', '4' => '5');

$result = $proxy->call(
    $session,
    'order_shipment.create',
    array(
        $orderIncrementId,
        $itemsQty
    )
);
```

This should work out for your bundled products as well.

For more information, have a look at the documentation:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/sales_order_shipment.create.html